# Using LIKE with domestic language in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I am using a SQL Server database, and I am storing `Malayalam` names in my tables. I just want to write a query for filtering names using some Malayalam words.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE mal_Name LIKE '@word%'
```

`@word` contain `Malayalam words`.

How can I achieve this? Please share any ideas.

EDIT

[image: This is my table, rm_Malayalam_name contains Malayalam name]

This is my table, rm_Malayalam_name contains Malayalam name. And my Query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM Purchase.tblRawMaterials 
WHERE rm_malayalam_name LIKE '%കദളിപഴം%'
```

It doesn't work. The entry is there but while executing this query nothing is shown

Comment: Make sure that (1) your column in the database is `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` to support your language, and also, when specifying such string literals, **always** prefix them with an `N` to make it a Unicode string literal: `where rm_malayalam_name LIKE N'%കദളിപഴം%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to do something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE mal_Name LIKE '%'+@word+'%'`

This will work if `@Word` is a single word, however if you want to take in multiple words you are going to need something a bit more complex.

UPDATE:
Having seen your new edits I would suspect that the reason it is not selecting is due to the encoding

Try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE mal_Name LIKE N'%'+@word+'%'`

or

```
select * from Purchase.tblRawMaterials where rm_malayalam_name like N'%കദളിപഴം%'
```

Comment: @word is a malayalam phrase and mal_Name is the column which stores malayalam(Domestic Language) values

Comment: if you update your question with some sample data from the table and some of the data you will be wanting to search for it would make things a bit clearer but my above solution should work, it will find any data within the mal_name column which contains the @words phrase

Comment: +1 Probably doesn't need the preceding '%' from the question, only the following '%' - if so, a `like @Word+'%'` (ie. starting with @Word) search should be *much* faster than a "containing @Word" search, since it doesn't need to search the whole string and may be able to make use of existing indexes.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: Edited. Please check.

Comment: @Nithesh, it still isn't clear whether you are trying to select all values of mal_Name containing @Word, or only those beginning with `@Word` - the first query in your question implies the latter, while the second implies the former. Also, it looks like there is an issue with your database *client* software (SSMS?) not being set up to handle Malayalam characters - your screenshot shows the Malayalam names being displayed as untranslated characters.

Comment: Good Point Mark,  @Nithesh what is the datatype of the rm_malayalam_name column?

Comment: @Nithesh ok when you inserted data into this column did you do N'കദളിപഴം' or just 'കദളിപഴം'  The issue may be that your data isnt inserted properly

Comment: @ Purplegoldfish:just 'കദളിപഴം'

Comment: @Nithesh ok re insert some of the text using N'കദളിപഴം' then try the select again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading up on SQL's [full-text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142587.aspx) It will almost certainly be more efficient than `LIKE '%word%'`

How many words will you be searching on? How big is the column? These factors might influence what the best option is.